# Dual Booting Windows and Ubuntu 18.04 - Ubuntu Not Showing Windows Free Space Partition When Installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I am attempting to dual boot windows and ubuntu 18 LTS (as of today 12.14.19).

I have formatted my usb drive with etcher and installed the ubuntu iso... this worked fine. Then I went into Windows 10 Disk Manager and shrunk my C drive and allotted 200GB of "Free Space" for ubuntu to go into. I turned off Safe Mode in Bios. I plug in my usb, restart, press f12 to see my boot menu. I boot into my usb/ubuntu and ubuntu boots up fine through the grub loader.

Once I am in Ubuntu I open the terminal and type 'gparted', when the GUI opens it only shows one partition which is dev/sda and is only the 30GB's of my usb stick. I do not see the 200GB I allotted in Windows 10 Disk Manager. So even when I try to partition the space manually I only have 30GB's to work with. Why doesn't ubuntu recognize my 200GB of space?

FYI in BIOS I have SATA not AHCI checked

***Screenshot of partitions in Windows:***

[image]

***Screenshot of partitions in Ubuntu:***

[image]

***Clicking on dropdown menu gparted:***

[image]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, I am not sure but the free space could be a part of Windows created logical drives. So from other OS(s) it looks like a Windows LVM partition.

Comment: Screenshots of what Windows and Ubuntu tools show of your drive would be helpful. Could be Windows Logical Volume, could be Windows Dynamic Disk, could be something else. So far this seems more like a Windows support question than an Ubuntu question.

Comment: Gparted only shows 1 disk at a time. It's showing the USB-connected drive in your photo. Use the dropdown menu at upper right corner of Gparted to see other disks. "Free Space" is not a partition, it's just empty disk space which needs to be partitioned and formatted with a filesystem. You can do that in Gparted.

Comment: Hi kreemoweet, I added another photo. In gparted when I click the drop down in the upper right hand corner, the only option available is the usb stick. Where is the free space?

Comment: It shows bitlocker encrypted, which then Linux cannot see. You also typically need AHCI, not RAID/Intel RST mode for drive.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: Hi oldfred, when I go into windows settings bitlocker is not turned on, would this still affect it? Also in BIOS if I try to change from RAID to AHCI it spits out a warning saying if I change it, my machine may not boot up...is this something to be concerned with or should I just change the RAID to AHCI?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, do NOT create the dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu. When  Windows 10 gets an Update, it will change and mess up the UEFI dual boot system.

Best way to have both is two different hard drives, hooked up with a switcher. That's what I am doing.

It does save your both of your OS and save your time to Reinstall everything again.